# Do we need to wrap event in a method in POM selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I am working on POM automation framework using selenium C#. I just had a question in my mind. Is there any benefit of warping  events like click or displayed in a method?

```
public void ClickConfirmDelete()
        {
            confirmDeleteBtn.Click();
        }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] with us.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of [*Page Object Design Pattern*](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern) , POM provides the following advantages :

- There is a clean separation between *Test Code* and *Page specific Code* such as locators and layout.
- There is a single repository for the services or operations [interms of `methods()`] offered by the page rather than having these services scattered throughout your *Tests*.

In both cases this allows any modifications required due to UI changes to all be made in one place. Hence you need to warp up the events like `click()` or `isDisplayed()` methods in a `function()` call.